# Executing a command inside docker shows wrong $PATH

Tags: linux, bash, docker

I am trying to run a bash command inside docker from host:

```
$ docker exec -it -u weiss apollo_dev /bin/bash -c "rosbag"

/bin/bash: rosbag: command not found
```

So I tried:

```
$ docker exec -it -u weiss apollo_dev /bin/bash -c "echo \$PATH"

/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin
```

But when I run docker interactively:

```
$ docker exec -it -u weiss apollo_dev /bin/bash
weiss@docker$ echo $PATH

/usr/local/cuda-8.0/bin:/home/tmp/ros/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin
```

Any reason why I am getting different results for `$PATH`?

Comment: Can you add your image’s `Dockerfile` and any other details necessary to produce a [mcve]?  Is this actually related to your actual application — when it calls subprocesses, can it correctly find the programs it needs to run?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This path is most likely changed in your `.bashrc` file, and this file is not loaded when the shell is non interactive (see https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Bash-Startup-Files)

So `/bin/bash` will load it, `/bin/bash -c` will not

Comment: Aaaand (most of the times) you can load it with `-l` : `/bin/bash -l -c 'echo $PATH'`

Comment: ...but many common Docker paths don’t load a `.bashrc` at all, and it’s not a great idea to depend on any settings there.

Answer (score 2):

Here you are getting de $PATH of your Host. Before you run the container the variable is replace for the host's $PATH.

```
$ docker exec -it -u weiss apollo_dev /bin/bash -c "echo \$PATH"
```

You need to pass the command without replace the variable, so when run the command in the container just invoke the $PATH variable.

```
$ docker exec -it -u weiss apollo_dev /bin/bash -c 'echo \$PATH'
```

Te 'apostrophe' is the key. Bye